# Using LayoutConstraints just for orientation changes?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

When I use the Storyboard to add constraints to button positions etc, I get super smooth transitions on orientation changes. The buttons move over to their new respective positions.

But I use `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` to move the elements around the screen.

Now I almost started writing custom-animation-logic for orientation changes. But there must be some easier way!? Can I turn constraints on before the orientation change and lift them again afterwards or something?

I tried using the following to make my item 'stick' to the bottom of the screen, but it didn't work.

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: super.bottomLayoutGuide, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.centerPositionButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
```

I'm currently trying out a lot of stuff, but something tells me I can't be the first one to try this.

Comment: This just creates the constraint object. To do something, it must be added to a view or activated.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `NSLayoutConstraint`s for this seems to be the right approach.
Thank you gnasher729 for pointing out that I'm simply using it wrong.